# Electrical modeling of multilayer structure

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, capacitance, modeling

If I have a construction of layers wherein the topmost layer is conductive, followed by two different insulation materials in between, and a bottom structural layer that is a partially conductive composite, how can I model this electrically?
[image]

Considering these are huge area layers (10m<sup>2</sup> each), would this constitute the electrical equivalent of a stackup?

[image]

Additionally, if I ground the structural material to Earth ground, do I have to worry about charge buildup at the two conductive plates?

EDIT: Adding complexity, if there's a conductive material (CM2) beneath this stackup some distance, d, away, how can I assess the impact on the CM2 in the presence of charge buildup when the structural material is left ungrounded?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> how can I model this electrically?

It really depends on what you need to model and to what accuracy. If you are measuring something below 100Mhz the somethin like the model you have would be accepable. A DC model would look like the one you have. If you need to model something in the GHz, you'll also have to model the dielectric and you may have capacitance of layers/ transmittance/reflectance and absorbtion that you need to worry about, a simple circuit model might also be inadequate.

> Additionally, if I ground the structural material to Earth ground, do
> I have to worry about charge buildup at the two conductive plates?

Whenever you have two conductive surfaces, they form a capaictor. If the structural material is grounded, then one end would be grounded which may be good or bad for your application vs a floating conductive plate that could be any potential. If you apply a voltage to the top conductor the bottom conductor will respond and change it's voltage via capacitor models.

Comment: What would be bad about it? Also what would the model look like for GHz

Comment: Depends on the materials

Comment: CM1 and CM2 are copper, Ins 1 is polyurethane, Ins 2 is teflon. Structure is graphite-epoxy composite

Comment: The model will look simmilar, but you'll have to substitute an parallel resistance and also care about how E_r is affecting capacitance. You may also need to substitute in  series inductance and resistance for any wires attached to the device. pF's will make a difference.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, any chance you could show the corrected model? A visual would be very helpful

Comment: I could, What is the application and frequency range?

Comment: Its for EMI shielding and frequency up to 12 GHz

Comment: When you say the bottom conductor "will respond and change its voltage via capacitor models" how would that work with a partially conductive graphite-epoxy conductor? If it is not as conductive as copper, will it able to balance charges with the top conductor?

Comment: If you want to model 12GHz you'll need a 2D or 2.5D EMFEM

Comment: could you share the model you described in words in previous comments for a visual of that comment?

Comment: What is in the gap between the structural material and the CM2?

Comment: the gap is filled with air